# rails :conditions to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to turn this for rails 4. Im building a message app using some code from a old rails app for pratice and need this code.

```
:conditions => ["messages.sender_deleted = ?", false]
```

user.rb

```
as_many :sent_messages,
  :class_name => 'Message',
  :primary_key=>'user_id',
  :foreign_key => 'sender_id',
  :conditions => ["messages.sender_deleted = ?", false]

  has_many :received_messages,
  :class_name => 'Message',
  :primary_key=>'user_id',
  :foreign_key => 'recepient_id',
  :conditions => ["messages.recepient_deleted = ?", false]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions now come first, so something such as:

```
has_many :sent_messages, 
  -> { where('messages.sender_deleted = ?', false) },
  class_name: Message,
  primary_key: 'user_id',
  foreign_key: 'sender_id'

has_many :received_messages, 
  -> { where('messages.recipient_deleted = ?', false) },
  class_name: Message,
  primary_key: 'user_id',
  foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
```

See "option examples" on [this page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).